# Problem in limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose f(x) is a differentiable function and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{f'(x)} = 0. \\ \text{If } g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x), \text{ show that } \lim_{x \to \infty}{g(x)} = 0.$$

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on $[x,x+1]$.

Comment: Thanks! When I get f΄(c) = f(x+1) - f(x) = g(x), i will say that because this relationship holds for an arbitrary c, it will hold for every x in R and so lim g(x) = lim f΄(x) = 0 ?

Comment: The relationship does not hold for an arbitrary $c$ (I may be misinterpreting what you said here).  But for an arbitrary $x$, there is such a $c$. Point out that $c$ depends on $x$, call it $c_x$. Note for any $x$, you have $c_x\in(x,x+1)$. So as $x$ tends to infinity, so does $c_x$. So $g(x)=f'(c_x)$ ...

Comment: @ManosG You're welcome.